# SAS Dates - SEMIYEAR in Proc SQL

Tags: sas

The following works fine for me, as I want to select the YYYYQ value for a column to show the year and quarter:

```
proc sql;
  select YYQ(year(datepart(betdate))
       , QTR(datepart(betdate))) FORMAT=YYQN. as yearquarter
       , QTR(datepart(betdate)) as semiyear
  from &dsn;
quit;
```

How can I calculate the 'SEMIYEAR' instead of QTR? I can find refernces to it in the SAS documentation, but can't seem to get it to work. I want to show YYYYS, as it the year and the year 'half'.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of one value for `betdate` and how you want it displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not exactly a format or function for that, unfortunately.  Do you need the date part of the value to persist, or just the value "20131"?  (In your YYQ, for example, the underlying value is an actual date, which corresponds to the first date in the period of 2013Q1, so Jan 1; it's just displayed as 20131).

If you just want to display the value, you can do something pretty simple, like this:

```
proc sql;
  select YYQ(year(datepart(betdate))
       , QTR(datepart(betdate))) FORMAT=YYQN. as yearquarter
       , floor(QTR(datepart(betdate))/2)+1 as semiyear
  from test;
quit;
```

And append on the year if you want.  However that does not maintain the actual first-day-of-the-period value.  If you want to do *that*, you should use INTNX:

```
proc sql;
  select YYQ(year(datepart(betdate))
       , QTR(datepart(betdate))) FORMAT=YYQN. as yearquarter
       , intnx('SEMIYEAR',datepart(betdate),0,'b') FORMAT=DATE9. as semiyear
  from test;
quit;
```

That doesn't format it neatly, of course, so you would have to write your own format, unless I'm missing one that exists already; that's pretty easy though.

```
proc format;
value SEMIYEAR
'01JAN2013'd-'30JUN2013'd = '20131'
'01JUL2013'd-'31DEC2013'd = '20132'
;
quit;
```

Sadly you can't use picture formats to do this as far as I know - the documentation at least doesn't offer an option to display semiannual period.  You can either do like I did above and just explicitly specify the time periods in the range, or you can write a function format; see http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1eyyzaux0ze5ln1k03gl338avbj.htm for examples of how to do that.

Edit: Here's an example that mostly works.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.functions.smd;
   function sfmt(date) $;
      length snum $5;
      snum = put(year(date)*10+floor(QTR(date)/2)+1,5.);
      return(snum);
   endsub;
run;

options cmplib=(work.functions);
proc format;
value semiyear
other=[sfmt()];
quit;

data test2;
set test;
x=put(datepart(betdate),semiyear.);
put x=;
run;
proc sql;
  select YYQ(year(datepart(betdate))
       , QTR(datepart(betdate))) FORMAT=YYQN. as yearquarter
       , intnx('SEMIYEAR',datepart(betdate),0,'b') FORMAT=SEMIYEAR5. as semiyear
  from test;
quit;
```

However, for some odd reason in my session at least the PROC SQL returns goofy characters instead of 20131.  The data step returns the correct answer in the log.  Not sure if this is a bug or if i'm doing something very slightly wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why do I need the '+1' in 'floor(QTR(datepart(betdate))/2)+1'?

Comment: I'm adjusting it to give you 1 or 2 not 0 or 1, though I think that actually is slightly off when I look at it now - the +1 needs to be inside the division [so, floor( (qtr(datepart(betdate))+1)/2)].  You want 1 and 2 as results, and floor(1/2) = 0.  So adjust 1,2,3,4 to be 2,3,4,5 and you have 2,3 /2 = 1 and 4,5 /2 = 2.

Comment: Great! I was getting three 'semi'-years there for a while! Works great. As per your first suggestion: I had planned to get the year and the semi-year and concatenate them using 'cats()'. unfortunately, when I ran 'proc rank' on that it refused to work as the 20111 or 20112 was a char value. Is there a quick way to change that into a number so that 'proc rank' will work on it?

Comment: Just do the trick I do in PROC FCMP; add year*10 to semiyear.

Comment: Great: this seems to work 'year(datepart(betdate))*10 + floor( (qtr(datepart(betdate))+1)/2) as yearsemiyear'.